# Hover over description woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I've had a search and there are a few in which relate to my query although they aren't as specific, also tried some plugins but don't seem to click for me.

The goal I have is when the user is on the shop page they can hover over a thumbnail to which they see the description for this product by grabbing that data from that said product thumbnail.

Example (no hover):

http://s22.postimg.org/yiedgbpep/Screen_Shot_2016_10_28_at_11_28_59.png

Example 2 (hover):

http://s17.postimg.org/49v85ev67/Screen_Shot_2016_10_28_at_11_29_33.png

I don't mind doing the css myself but the functionality side of this is where I'm struggling since I assumed it would be common enough and have a plugin to use to get started on it.

The above is my main query but if it's just as easy to answer the next part to this would be a creating a custom class under each category so it would be styled a certain colour for each category but the first question is my main query.

I'm using the latest version of Wordpress & WooCommerce.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
#box{

  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:yellow;
}
#box:hover {
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  width:50px;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:50px;
  visibility:visible;
  cursor:pointer;
  }
```

I hope it will help you. It is simple example what you must to do.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't the answer, the css is the easier task to carry out for this. I'm trying to pull the information that is in the description of that product over the thumbnail on the shop page then I'll look into styling this.